# Spring boot flyway migration not being triggered on application startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, flyway

I am trying to setup flyway in a spring boot project to manage DB migrations. However, despite following this article: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot I am not able to setup DB by flyway automatically.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:db/testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

flyway.url = jdbc:h2:file:db/testdb
#flyway.schemas = PUBLIC
flyway.user = sa
flyway.password = password
```

V1_0_0__init_script.sql

```
create table demo_flyway(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sometext VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO demo_flyway(sometext) values ('some text');
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway.demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>flyway.demo</name>
    <description>Flyway demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.java

```
package com.example.flyway.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using spring boot version 2.3.1. The flyway properties starts with spring.flyway.*. convert flyway.* to spring.flyway.* and it will start working. You can also enable it explicitly spring.flyway.enabled=true.

Comment: Try not to use `flyway.*` properties. Try to use only `spring.datasource*` properties. Spring Boot must perform all the magic. I use this way in my solution.

Comment: Thanks for that @Akash. Now I am getting an exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException`

Comment: Had to convert `spring-boot-starter` to `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` to make it work. Had to add Spring Data JDBC just to make flyway work, I don't need it otherwise. Thanks guys.